# Laravel how to register a user with a default image in user::create

Tags: php, html, laravel

I wanted to make it that when you register a new user it comes with a default picture :

`https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Portrait_Placeholder.png`

I tried something like this but it doesn't work the image doesn't stays in the database, how would I do it?

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = "/registando";

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'profile_image' => 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Portrait_Placeholder.png'],
            
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Why is there a ] after your profile_image?
2. Is the profile_image set as "fillable" in the User model?

Comment: I had something else in there i just forgot to delete that ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have to change your `User` model and add the `profile_image` to fillable array:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'profile_image'
    ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your user model file add fillable for `profile_image` like this

```
protected $fillable = ['profile_image'];
```

and make sure, your `users` table had `profile_image` columns